# Product can not be deleted

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am having the following problem in my project. I am trying to delete an added product but unfortunately, it cannot be deleted. So let me show you my code.

First I have the Product.js model.

```
static deleteById(prodId){
        const db = getDb();
        return db
        .collection('products')
        .deleteOne({_id: new mongodb.ObjectId(prodId) })
        .then(result => {
            console.log('Deleted');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
    }
```

Then I use **deleteById** function in my controller Admin.js file.

```
exports.postDeleteProduct = (req, res, next) => {
  const prodId = req.params.productId;
  Product.deleteById(prodId)
      .then(() => {
          console.log('DESTROYED PRODUCT');
          res.redirect('/admin/products');
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
};
```

After doing that I am creating the necessary route in the routes->admin.js file.

```
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');

const adminController = require('../controllers/admin');

const router = express.Router();


// /admin/add-product => GET
router.get('/add-product', adminController.getAddProduct);

// admin/products => GET
router.get('/products', adminController.getProducts);

// /admin/add-product => POST
router.post('/add-product', adminController.postAddProduct);

router.get('/edit-product/:productId', adminController.getEditProduct);

router.post('/edit-product', adminController.postEditProduct);

router.post('/delete-product', adminController.postDeleteProduct);

module.exports = router;
```

Finally, there is the HTML file which contains the delete button.

```
        <main>
            <% if (prods.length > 0) { %>
                <div class="grid">
                    <% for (let product of prods) { %>
                        <article class="card product-item">
                            <header class="card__header">
                                <h1 class="product__title">
                                    <%= product.title %>
                                </h1>
                            </header>
                            <div class="card__image">
                                <img src="<%= product.imageUrl %>" alt="<%= product.title %>">
                            </div>
                            <div class="card__content">
                                <h2 class="product__price">$
                                    <%= product.price %>
                                </h2>
                                <p class="product__description">
                                    <%= product.description %>
                                </p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card__actions">
                                <a href="/admin/edit-product/<%= product._id %>?edit=true" class="btn">Edit</a>
                                <form action="/admin/delete-product" method="POST">
                                    <input type="hidden" value="<%= product._id %>" name="productId">
                                    <button class="btn" type="submit">Delete</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                        <% } %>
                </div>
                <% } else { %>
                    <h1>No Products Found!</h1>
                    <% } %>
        </main>
        <%- include('../includes/end.ejs') %>
```

Here is my [repo](https://github.com/theo82/NodeJs-Eshop).

How can the delete problem be fixed?

Comment: Is deleteById logging an error or are you seeing the 'Deleted' console message? If so, what is it? If there's no error from the function, are you sure it's being called? If you're not seeing an error, try putting a console.log("starting deleteById function call") as the first line in the function to see if it's being called

Comment: @Mark. I added the log message in the deleteById function and I see it in the log screen when the delete button is clicked. So that function is being called correctly. Something else is happening and can not see it.

Comment: After that log message, are seeing another one from one of these? .then(result => {
            console.log('Deleted');
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });

Comment: @Mark. I am seeing Deleted. As you can see the deleteById function is called ok.

Comment: Can you also log the prodId in the model and confirm that it is the same in the mongodb document?

Comment: Also, can you console log the result inside the .then() from the deleteOne()?